# Conditionally Update Several Records Across Tables Based On Value Of A Column's Value For Each Row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to streamline updating database records. I've investigated several methods and options but any that focus on PHP instead of MySQL would require hundreds if not thousands of queries, that is clearly not desirable. I'm working with three tables, one contains rows that identify various aspects of a product, one that connects the descriptive values to products and finally the products. The descriptive table has a column that is to trigger an update for all products that use it. The trouble I'm having is that the update might require the product use a new description and that description might have to be created and then set in the product connect table. The description table is also used to calculate the new value based off of another entry.

Description Table:

```
id | unit |       type      | update
------------------------------------
1    4oz    weight                      
2    3      servings             1
3    7oz    weight                      
4    4      servings            
5    0.66   price_per_serving
6    0.49   price_per_oz
```

Connector Table:

```
id | description_id | product_id
--------------------------------
1          1              1
2          2              1
3          2              2
4          4              3
```

Product Table:

```
id |    name    | price
-----------------------
1    soup         1.99
2    crackers     2.00
3    chips        0.79
4    candy bar    0.99
```

So from the example tables I need to find that item 2 in the description table needs updating. Through the connector table I see the soup and crackers have three servings. I need to take the price of each item using entry 2 and divide it by the number of servings. If that new value isn't in the description table (say 0.78 price_per_serving), it needs to be created and the connector table needs to hold the id of the existing matching entry if one exists or the new one that was created if it didn't. The entry update field will now be cleared.

I can perform all of the functions with PHP no problem, as you can see though it would just place an enormous burden on resources.

I've been trying to wrap my head around sub-queries and reading plenty of articles, manuals and other questions on this site but I'm just so overwhelmed I don't know how to get started. I've found queries like the example shown in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542571/mysql-case-when-then-returning-wrong-data-type-blob) but my MySQL experience is mostly select, update, insert.